# Access nested params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
{"organisation"=>"{\"current_page\":\"home_page\",\"is_worker\":true}", "controller"=>"my_profile/worker/jobs", "action"=>"managers", "format"=>"json"} permitted: false>
```

def managers
binding.pry
end

I am making an axios request to the fetch data. In the controller action, I have defined binding.pry to check the params but I am not able to figureout how can I access current_page params.

I tried something like

```
params[:organisation][:current_page]
```

But I am getting error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I am about to access the organisation

```
params[:organisation]
```

And I am getting the output as

```
{\"current_page\":\"home_page\",\"is_worker\":true}
```

Please help me solve how can I access current_page and is_worker

Axios request

```
data = {current_page: type, is_worker: true }
this.$axios.get(url, { params: { organisation: data } })
```

Comment: `params[:organisation]` contains JSON, [you have to parse it](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html). Why it contains JSON, and not a Ruby Hash, I can't say without seeing what sent those params.

Comment: @Schwern please check axios request section in the quetion

Answer (score 1):

The value of `organisation` key is json string, so you should parse it firstly

```
JSON(params[:organisation])['current_page']
```